# ASP.NET Minimal API - Access IConfiguration

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0, c#-10.0

Is it possible to access the the IConfiguration in the new ASP.NET Minimal API? I do not see the possibility to do such thing.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using MudBlazor.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
...

builder.Services.AddMyServiceWithConfiguration(XXXX.Configuration);

var app = builder.Build();

....

app.Run();
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use `builder.Configuration`. In this [example](https://github.com/DamianEdwards/MinimalApiPlayground/blob/main/src/Todo.EFCore/Program.cs), the connection string is retrieved in the second line of actual code:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("TodoDb") 
                       ?? "Data Source=todos.db";


builder.Services.AddSqlite<TodoDb>(connectionString)
                .AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
```

The [WebApplicationBuilder.Configuration](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/DefaultBuilder/src/WebApplicationBuilder.cs#L112) property is a [Microsoft.Extensions.ConfigurationManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationmanager?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) instance that implements `IConfigurationRoot` and `IConfiguration`, so it can be used to load config settings or use extension methods like `GetConnectionString`

Once the application is built, configuration is accessible through the [WebApplication.Configuration](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/DefaultBuilder/src/WebApplication.cs#L45) property. This is just a call to `Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>()`:

```
public IConfiguration Configuration => 
    _host.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access ConfigurationManager (builder.Configuration) which is an implementation of IConfigurationBuilder, IConfigurationRoot and IConfiguration

After your application is build (builder.Build()), you can access it using
`app.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>()`